# Unlock button before call a function

Tags: javascript

I have the javascript function:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="bt_gravar" onclick="bloqueia();" style="width: 100%;">Cadastrar <i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>

function bloqueia(){
   $("#bt_gravar").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   gravaAgenda();
   $("#bt_gravar").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

**gravaAgenda() is a AJAX function**

I want to lock the button to avoid the user double click. And next the function, unlock the button.

But it's not work. I can click on the button more times.

Any ideia?

Comment: Is the gravaAgenda function an AJAX ?

Comment: What does not work? What is `gravaAgenda`?

Comment: @KenLee yes. Is a AJAX

Comment: @epascarello Is a AJAX function

Comment: Then you should trigger removeaAttr after the AJAX data returns

Comment: try this. as document.getElementById.  (http://jsfiddle.net/SPddm/300/)

Comment: @KenLee it's works when I put remove after AJAX. Thanks

Comment: Great. Have a nice day

Comment: @KenLee if you like, post the answer to get the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay removing the disabled attribute until you get the result back from the ajax fn

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="bt_gravar" style="width: 100%;">Cadastrar <i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#bt_gravar").click(function() {
       $("#this").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       gravaAgenda();
    })
    
}
function gravaAgenda() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    method:'post',
    data:{}
  }).done(function() {
    $("#bt_gravar").removeAttr('disabled');
  });
}
```